# Finding the roots of a 3rd degree polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, symmetric-polynomials

I found this question from an old math olympiad questionnaire.

Let A, B, and C be the roots of $$x^3-4x-8=0$$ Find the numerical value of the expression $$\frac{A+2}{A-2}+\frac{B+2}{B-2}+\frac{C+2}{C-2}$$

I tried using Rational Roots Theorem. And then, I realized this equation involves complex numbers. Afterwhich, I tried various manipulations. But everytime I do manipulate I either go back from where I started or I went off too far and probably did something wrong in my calculations. I also tried tried doing something like "let u be x squared" and then tried manipulations there. I did found a value for x which are 0,0,+/-2 sqrt of 3, and I know these are wrong, so I gave up.

I do not know how to continue or what else to try. Can anyone help?

Comment: You need not find the exact value of each root. You should use Viete's theorem instead since the expression is symmetric.

Comment: Personally, I found your hint easier to grasp than Muralidharan and lab's solutions. I just think their works were too advanced for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: you're welcome. Well I'd say theirs are actually easier to follow because mine is just an idea but theirs span the idea into concrete steps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{A+2}{A-2}+\frac{B+2}{B-2}+\frac{C+2}{C-2} &= \frac{A-2+4}{A-2}+\frac{B-2+4}{B-2}+\frac{C-2+4}{C-2} \\
&=3 +\frac{4}{A-2}+\frac{4}{B-2}+\frac{4}{C-2} 
\end{align*}
    The equation with $\alpha - 2, \beta -2, \gamma - 2$ as roots (where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are the roots of the given equation) is 
    $(y+2)^3 - 4(y+2) - 8 = y^3 + 6y^2 + 8y - 8 = 0$ and we want the sum of the reciprocals of the roots of this equation. This is 
    $\frac{8}{8} = 1$. Thus
    \begin{align*}
 \frac{A+2}{A-2}+\frac{B+2}{B-2}+\frac{C+2}{C-2} &= 3+4 = 7
 \end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your help. Honestly, I do not quite understand your solution fully however I really do wish to understand it. May I know how you got the second equation from your first? I did not quite get that part.

Comment: Since $\alpha,\beta, \gamma$ satisfies the given equation,  we need the equation satisfied by $\alpha-2, \beta-2, \gamma-2$. Put $y = x-2$. Then $x=y+2$. Substituting $y+2$ in the given equation, we obtain the equation satisfied by $\alpha-2, \beta-2, \gamma-2$.

Comment: I did not understand the reason why you have to change (A+2/A-2)+(B+2/B-2)+(C+2/C-2) into 3+(4/A-2)+(4/B-2)+(4/C-2). I know how you did it. I just do not know why. Also, why should we get the sum of the reciprocals? Is it a general rule or am I just missing something out?

Comment: Given an equation, it is easier to compute the symmetric expressions involving roots using Vieta's formulas. In fact, if $\alpha,\beta, \gamma$ are the roots of $x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$, then $\alpha+\beta+\gamma = -a, \alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha = b, \alpha\beta\gamma = -c$. You can see that $\frac{1}{\alpha} +\frac{1}{\beta}+\frac{1}{\gamma} = \frac{\alpha\beta+\beta\gamma+\gamma\alpha}{\alpha\beta\gamma} = -\frac{b}{c}$. This is what we have used.

Comment: You may see that we first formed the equation whose roots are $A-2, B-2, C-2$ and used the formula above to compute $\frac{1}{A-2}+\frac{1}{B-2}+\frac{1}{C-2}$ which is much easier than simplifying the given expression directly and applying Vieta's formulas. These "tricks" you learn as you go by.

Comment: Ahhhh.. Now I understand. That is so cool! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6):

Let $y=\dfrac{x+2}{x-2}$

Using [Componendo and Dividendo](https://brilliant.org/wiki/componendo-and-dividendo/),  $\dfrac{y+1}{y-1}=\dfrac x2\iff x=?$

Replace the value of $x$ in the given equation to form a cubic equation in $y$

$$(2-1)y^3-(4+3)y^2+\cdots=0$$

Use Veita's formula to find the required sum $$=\dfrac71$$

Comment: Thank you for your help. I also do not understand your solution since I am not very familiar with the Componendo and Dividendo. But, I do really love to understand your solution. My first question: why did you set y as x+2/x-2 in the first place?

Comment: @CarlTerenceValdellon, For the last Question, observe what we need to calculate. Read the link on Componendo and Dividendo.

Comment: @labbhattarjee: Nice ref! (+1)

Comment: @CarlTerenceValdellon, See also : http://www.iitjeemathematics.com/conte/quadratic-equations/14-transformation-of-equations